# GL Error in Generate Invoices from Appointments

Tags: acumatica

I have had added a custom field in Customer called 'UsrCustomerNote' which was used in Appointments page so that user would be able to update the field from Appointments page too while selecting the Customer ID in the page. And that is working perfectly fine.

But now the problem is in 'Generate Invoices from Appointments' page where if I trigger 'Process All' action having customer with value in 'UsrCustomerNote' field (Here the customer HAGGEN001), it gives me the error like this.

[image]

And the thing is I can't even see the source code of Business Logic.
[image]